# Create words based on input like "otb" into "bot"

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show a list of all words that can be created given a certain input. For this, I use all words that contain 12 characters.

I thought of SQL be able to see if letters are within a word. So jecobvizedti can become objectivized but if I would give jecobvizeti (without the d) it can also become objectivizes. This would also be the desired result.

Is there a way to let SQL determine which words match as they contain the characters of the input string. At first, I tried 12 separate fields and store 1 character into each field for the 12 character words. But that didn't make sense at all.

This is case-insensitive as I make sure the input is in lower case.
It should only support letters. No digits, spaces, or punctuation.
As for the performance, a max of 10 sec would be nice. I think SQL can manage that.

Edit: Solution of Ruud Helderman and the question linked doesn't work 100%. If I have the following letters: "beergtoltrot" it comes with a word that contains the letter "c" or with a word that contains the letter "v" which are not in the input string.

Comment: Case-sensitive or case-insensitive? Only letters or also digits, punctuation, spaces? Any performance demands?

Comment: case-insensitive, only letters, max of 10 seconds. Good questions I shall update the main post with the answers

Comment: Is this about _finding_ (in a table, e.g. a dump of an English dictionary) matching words, or about _generating_ all possibilities? I assume the former, as the latter would yield half a billion permutations.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Yes it was the former. That posts looks very good, weird that I did not find it.

Comment: @RuudHelderman it works like a charm

Comment: I am reopening because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776870/mysql-find-words-containing-all-letters-at-any-place seems to answer a related, but not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this for a lot of words and you are not, for example saying that 'otb' should match 'brought'.  That is you want *exactly* the same set of letters.

And how about getting the answer in a few *milliseconds*?

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    sorted VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    real_word VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(real_word),
    INDEX(sorted, real_word),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`sorted` contains the letters of `real_word` but rearranged in sorted order.

```
`sorted` => `real_word`
'bot' => 'bot'  -- this happens to be in order to start with.
'bcdeeiijotvz' => 'objectivized'
'aest' => 'seat'
'aest' => 'teas'
'aest' => 'eats'
'aest' => 'east'
```

But... You must do this sorting in two places:

- As you enter the data.
- As you look up the data.

And it is best to do the sorting in your client code.  The lookup in the single table a hundred thousand words will be very fast.

Comment: The solution I had doesn't work 100%. As it shows some words that contain letter which are not in the input string. But with your solution, I wonder how fast it will be as I have 25k words which contain 12 letters. If I have to put them in every possible order I will have a few million records

Comment: You only have to put the words in alphabetical order, not every possible order. This is the quickest way to do this kind of lookup

Comment: @Helper - There is exactly one row per input word.  The letters in `sorted` are alphabetized, not rearranged in all ways.  When looking up, you must also alphabetized the letters before doing the `SELECT`.  At this point, you might get multiple rows -- as in seat -> aest -> seat,teas,etas,east.  Give me an example of where the algorithm is failing for you.

Comment: The solution I am giving here is not the same as the one linked to previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
where word like '%o%' and
      word like '%b%' and
      word like '%t%'
```

There are tricks for splitting an input string into individual characters.  But if you can do this in the application, this shoudl work.

Comment: With 25K words and 12 LIKEs, this will work, but slowly.